# How to resolve dependencies and target framework for Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging nuget package which couldn't be installed

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to implement Push Notifications in Xamarin.Forms.

It appears I need to use the NuGet package Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging - as referenced, for example, in this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=le2lDY22xwM&t=1s

However, if I try and add this package to a vanilla Xamarin.Forms app, I get this error:
Package Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging 71.1740.0 is not compatible with netstandard2.0

I found this about this error, it's 2 years old but isn't really helpful:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/86307/xamarin-firebase-not-compatible-with-forms

I also can't comment on that post as the login appears to be broken.

How can I fix this error? (as an aside if anyone has a better suggestion for sending cross platform notifications in Xamarin.Forms I welcome it, I've tried AppCenter.ms but couldn't get that working either).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to follow this [tutorial here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-push)

You don't need to to install specifically version 71.1740.0. You can just install version 60.1142.1 and it works too.

This issue is mainly caused because of dependencies to Xamarin.Android.Support nuget packages and the Target Framework in your Android project.

[On this page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging/71.1740.0) you can find all dependencies related to Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging nuget package. If you go through dependencies of version 71.1740.0 you find that you need to set Target Framework to Android 9 in your project. See picture bellow.

[image: Target Framework Android 9]

To install latest Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging into Xamrin.Forms vanilla project you just need to change this Target Framework to Android 9.

Comment: Still errors for all 3 versions of Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging, even if I compile using Android 9 or 10. Examples using version 42 below:

Comment: NU1202 Package Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging 42.1021.1 is not compatible with xamarinios10

Comment: Package Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging 42.1021.1 is not compatible with netstandard2.0

Comment: @niico The version 42.1021.1 only supports Mondroid 7.0. Please follow the link https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging/42.1021.1 which I reffered and try to understand dependencies. I would restart Visual Studio and delete bin and obj folder after changing target framework.

Comment: Thanks, though having to do this to do something as basic as push notifications makes Xamarin.Forms pretty useless, no?

Comment: @niico I don't think so. You just need to understand these dependencies.

Comment: @niico If my answer helped you out feel free to accept it as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: If you want the link to the tutorial in English: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/previous-versions/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-push

Answer (score 1):

> However, if I try and add this package to a vanilla Xamarin.Forms app, I get this error: Package Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging 71.1740.0 is not compatible with netstandard2.0

According to your description, you only install this package into a Xamarin.Android project as there are no targets for this NuGet package to install into a PCL.

[image]

Look at the "Dependencies" on NuGet,In this case, only MonoAndroid90 is supported. This is synonymous with Xamarin.Android targeting API 28 minimum. So please check **Compile using Android version:(Target Framework)** and **Target Android version** is Android 9.0.

[image]